# If I use async task in an action definition, should that action be async related?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, async-await

Say I have

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
...
    public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction()
    {
        DoSomethingSync();
        return View();
    }
```

Is it well used? Shouldn't it have at least something Async to justify the "async Task L..." definition? Every action in this controller seems to follow the same pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a reason why the compiler is giving you a warning. Do not ignore it. If your method has no need to be `async`, then **DO NOT** mark it as such. As soon as you simply just include the word `async` in your method signature, the compiler will generate a bunch of code to support asynchrony. This extra code will run for no reason, degrading performance.

As an example to just show you how wasteful it is, I ran a very basic benchmark comparing two methods using `BenchmarkDotNet`:

```
[Benchmark]
public static async Task<string> AsyncString()
{
    return "This is my string This is my string This is my string This is my string This is my string";

}

[Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
public static string String()
{
    return "This is my string This is my string This is my string This is my string This is my string";
}
```

Results:

```
|      Method |       Mean |     Error |    StdDev | Ratio | RatioSD |  Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
|------------ |-----------:|----------:|----------:|------:|--------:|-------:|------:|------:|----------:|
|      String |  0.0000 ns | 0.0000 ns | 0.0000 ns |     ? |       ? |      - |     - |     - |         - |
| AsyncString | 27.2304 ns | 0.7644 ns | 2.1685 ns |     ? |       ? | 0.0172 |     - |     - |      72 B |
```

Just using `async` caused 72 bytes of allocations that will put pressure on the GC and is so much slower than the alternative. Bottom line is don't ignore compiler warnings.